Can I use one useState only?
Below my code
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {   

    const [cartState, setCartState] = useState(null);

    function Cart(name, value) {
        setCartState({[name]: value})                
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        Cart(["a"], "111");
        Cart(["b"], "222");        
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {cartState["a"]}
                {cartState["b"]}
            </div>
        </>
    )    
}

export default App;


Below is my error message:
App.js:18  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'a')
    at App (App.js:18:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20103:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21626:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27490:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26596:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26505:1)

I am expecting to get the following output:
111
222
If my approach or my method does not work, please let me know how I can make it work. Thanks!

UseEffect runs at the end of the component, so when u r reading cardState on line 18, it is still null. Also, setCardState replaces the value of cardState, so it will not be appended and have {"b": "222"}, even if the useEffect runs. Please, clarify your usecase. If u just want to display the object values, u do not need useState or UseEffect, just use normal object declaration and use it.


Cannot read properties of null (reading 'a')

You're initializing state to null:
const [cartState, setCartState] = useState(null);

And trying to read properties from it:
<div>
  {cartState["a"]}
  {cartState["b"]}
</div>

Just as the error tells you, you can't read the property a (or b, or any other property) from null.
You could initialize state to an empty object:
const [cartState, setCartState] = useState({});

And/or you could use optional chaining to read values from it:
<div>
  {cartState?.["a"]}
  {cartState?.["b"]}
</div>


As an aside, you'll next find that only one of your two state updates is actually being set.  This is because you're updating the same state twice, and to two different things.  So the latter will "win".
If the goal is to combine the states into a single object, you need to preserve the previous state of that object as well:
setCartState(prev => { ...prev, [name]: value})


Thanks for both your help! What I want to do is when I add computer #1 to  shopping cart. The "Pickup" and "Ship" pictures show up. And the "Ship" picture is selected, and the message is show up. Now when I click on "Pickup" (instead of "Ship") picture, the "Ship" message is disappeared and a list of "protection plans" is show up. Now I add computer #2 to the shopping cart and I click on the "Pickup" picture on the computer #2, a list of different protection plans is show up for the computer #2, ...., and so on. Please note that I have no problem for getting protection plans from the database.

@Cookie: I don't see how any of that description is related to the question above.  If you've encountered some other problem in some other code then that should probably be addressed in a separate Stack Overflow question.

Hello David, thanks for your advice! cartState is in fact a list of computer protection plans. I just did not use the right names / words. Let's say I have computer #1 and computer #2 on shopping cart page. Then {protectionPlansState["#1"]} is for computer #1 on the shopping cart page. And {protectionPlansState["#2"]} is for computer #2 on the shopping cart page, .. and so on. So when I click on "Pickup" on computer #1 then a list of protection plans show up for computer #1. And when I click on "Pickup" on computer #2 then protection plans show up for computer #2 on the shopping cart page.

@Cookie: That's all well and good, but you're still talking about things unrelated to the question above.  If you've encountered some other problem in some other code then that should probably be addressed in a separate Stack Overflow question.
